# Angular Material Table with multiple rows per record

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use `Angular Material` table to display records from a database table.

The issue is that there are a lot of fields on each record and my requirements is to show each record on 3 different table rows like this:

```
       <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Order<br/>Number</td>
            <td class="tableHeader"> Order<br/>Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Line<br/>Number</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Event<br/>Timestamp</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Event<br/>Reason</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Segment</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Carrier Code</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Origin</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Destination<br/>Type</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Destination<br/>Value</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Ship<br/>Complete</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Associated<br/>Order</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Associated<br/>Order line</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td class="tableHeader"> Iteration<br/>Count</td>
            <td class="tableHeader"> MDS Seq</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Movement<br/> Days</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Pricing<br/> Hours</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Ats MDS</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Ats Processing<br/> Hours</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Ats Transit<br/> Hours</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>    
            <td class="tableHeader"> (Final)<br/> Ship Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> (Final)<br/> Delivery Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Start<br/> Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Repromise<br/> Date</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>   
            <td class="tableHeader"> Orig<br/> delv Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Orig<br/> ship Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Nb Date</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader">Cust<br/> Spec</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Consolidation</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Holiday</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> No Ship</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Max<br/> Iteration</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Orde<br/>Cut Off</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Rele<br/> Cut Off</td> 
            <td class="tableHeader"> Credit<br/>Code</td>
        </tr> 
       </table>
```

so 3 html table rows per record.

I could not find any example with material table that spans multiple rows.

I can do this without angular material table easily but I want to benefit from using `mat-paginator` and sorting like [in this example](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/), which is easier if I use mat-table

Any ideas ?

Comment: Since you're not making a table, you should avoid using a table to display non-table content ... Besides, sorting and pagination are really easy to integrate to your custom components, maybe you should create one ?

Comment: What do you mean I am not making a table. It is a table, except that the record spans on 3 rows because it cannot fit all on one row

Comment: And in your example, the `field1` is the same as the `field16` and `field31` ? The column header describes them all as the same field ; is that true ?

Comment: no each field is different, so for example:   Account nbr, name, description, address, etc....   so in total there are 40+ header columns to show

Comment: So if your first field is "Account number" and your sixteenth one is "Address", both fields will be in the same column because they're aligned on two rows. How is that a table element ?

Comment: I changed the question to add what I need in html. as you can see there are 4 headers rows, which means I need 4 detail rows per record.

Comment: If it's only that, simply remove the border from the lines, and you got yourself your "table" !

Comment: Use the `multiTemplateDataRows` option on MatTable. You can then use more than one <tr> in your template for each data row.